# AABB Sweeping, algorithm to solve "stacking box" problem

Tags: collision-detection, algorithm, aabb

I'm currently working on a simple AABB collision system and after some fiddling the sweeping of a single box vs. another and the calculation of the response velocity needed to push them apart works flawlessly.

Now on to the new problem, imagine I'm having a stack of boxes which are falling towards a ground box which isn't moving:

[image]

Each of these boxes has a `vertical velocity` for the "gravity" value, let's say this velocity is `5`.

Now, the result is that they all fall into each other:

[image]

The reason is obvious, since all the boxes have a downward velocity of `5`, this results in no collisions when calculating the relative velocity between the boxes during sweeping.

> Note: The red ground box here is static (always 0 velocity, can utilize spatial partitioning ), and all dynamic > static collisions are resolved first, thus the fact that the boxes stop correctly at this ground box.

So, this seems to be simply an issue with the order the boxes are sweept against each other.

I imagine that sorting the boxes based on their `x` and `y` velocities and then sweeping these groups correctly against each other may resolve this issues.

So, I'm looking for algorithms / examples on how to implement such a system.

The code can be found here: https://github.com/BonsaiDen/aabb

The two files which are of interest are [box/Dynamic.lua](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/aabb/blob/master/box/Dynamic.lua) and [box/Manager.lua](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/aabb/blob/master/box/Manager.lua).

The project is using [Love2D](https://love2d.org/) in case you want to run it.

Comment: why don't you resolve static collisions first? and then you need to decrease your time steps.

Comment: Sorting from lowest to highest is important to get good stacked box behavior in traditional discrete collision/physics systems.  Unsure about swept volumes

Comment: @Gajet I'm already doing the static ones first (that's why they don't fall through the red box which is the ground in this case) but the white boxes need to stack on top of each other.

Comment: @seanmiddleditch That might work out as a quick fix, now the question is how to make it work in cases where the gravity is inverted.

Comment: Sort in order of gravity vector?

Comment: If it is using relative velocity, why is the difference not 5 when the first box hits (and halts) on the platform?

Comment: @seanmiddleditch Tried that, seems to work somewhat, but it pushes the lowest box into the ground :/

Comment: @Daniel The velocity for the first box is 5 and when it hits, the velocity needed to get out of the ground is -5 (thus cancelling out the vertical movement in that step and halting the box) but the first box happens to be resolved after the boxes on top of it, so when the box above it checks for collision, it still finds the lowest one as falling with 5 pixels per second and thus not colliding with it.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel, and what the next time step, after the first box is resolved. You should get a reactive second box then with dt*v penetration depth into the first box.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel again in discrete systems, that effect is resolved by running multiple iterations of the contact resolver every physics update.  It does not eliminate the innacuracies, but greatly reduces them.  A great great number of tweaks and special hacks are required to get good stacking behavior.  The only way to do it perfectly would be to use elastic bodies (no real objects are perfectly inelastic), infinitely small time steps, and resolve all collisions simultaneously.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is how other systems solve this problem but here is an idea:

1. first move all objects like you normally do.
2. resolve all static vs dynamic collisions.
3. resolve all dynamic vs dynamic collision.
4. for every dynamic object which had a collision resolve all collision.
5. repeat step 4 until either there is no collisions left or you reach a limit of some kind (for example you reach more than 10 iterations)

also as I previously mentioned reducing time step will surly help fixing that bug.

Comment: +1, this is pretty much the only reliable way to allow collisions to propagate across a chain of multiple objects in one time step. It occurs to me that simulating a [Newton's cradle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle) could make a good test case.